# Gitlab Ci saving artifacts after running gulp

Tags: gitlab, gulp, cicd

I am trying to run gulp and save compiled file to artifacts, but i cant make it work.

my gulp file works fine on local.

```js
const process = require('process');
var css = {
  src: process.cwd() + '/app/scss/style.scss',
  dest: process.cwd() +'/public/stylesheets'
};
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

function buildStyles() {
  return gulp.src(css.src)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(css.dest));
};

exports.buildStyles = buildStyles;
```

This is my .yaml file that passes, but the file my-build is empty

```yaml
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - deploy
# This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
build-job:
  stage: build
  image: node:12.22.6-alpine
  variables:
    TZ: "Europe/Stockholm"
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - mkdir my-build
    - cd my-build
    - npm i
    - npm i --g gulp
    - gulp buildStyles
    - echo "Compile complete."  
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 days
    paths: 
       - my-build
  allow_failure: false



deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually compiling anything? Can you show the output of the build? Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this could work if `gulp` locates your `src` and `dest` directories the same way. Either (1) your output directories are incorrectly relative to the root (not `my-build` or cwd) or (2) your src directories are incorrectly relative to cwd, resulting in nothing being compiled when you run gulp from an empty directory because there are no src files in `my-build`. Try adding `tree $CI_PROJECT_DIR` to the end of your build to see all the files...

Comment: @sytech i updated the post with the error i got, regarding tree $CI_PROJECT_DIR i am not sure if i added it to the right place, but i recive an error $ tree $CI_PROJECT_DIR
/bin/sh: eval: line 128: tree: not found

Comment: Seems like `tree` isn't installed in your image. you _can_ install tree or use `ls -R $CI_PROJECT_DIR` instead, but I think I see the problem in your build output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulp` is not placing its output files relative to your working directory. It will place output files as configured in your gulpfile. When the build starts, gulp is [changing the working directory](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/blob/da8241ecbacd59158deaa5471ff8a7f43901a94b/index.js#L189-L197) back to the project root:

> [19:19:04] Working directory changed to /builds/stefan_avramovic/nodejs-code-build
> [19:19:04] Using gulpfile /builds/stefan_avramovic/nodejs-code-build/gulpfile.js

Thus, as according to your `target` configurations, your outputs will be placed in the `dist` and `public` directories, relative to the project root, not `my-build` -- the `dest` paths are going to be defined the same way gulp is finding your `src` files using the defined relative paths.

To fix this you could:

1. change the directory you artifact to your `dist`/`public` directories, as gulp is currently using
2. change your gulp config -- use a different target of `my-build` or set `cwd` accordingly in your gulp dest [options](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest#options)
3. move the target directories after the build is finished (e.g. `mv $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist $CI_PROJECT_DIR/my-build`)